# Perl format number to time?

Tags: perl, time, format

I have two fields in a .CSV file I'm parsing through that are supposed to represent time.  Currently, they are either 5 or 6 digit numbers (i.e. 85323 would be 8:53:23, or 163211 would be 16:32:11).  I need to throw the colons (:) in there.  Would something like

```
strptime->strftime
```

using

```
Time::Piece
```

work for something like that?  Or maybe not since they're currently treated as a VARCHAR to load into a MySQL table and should probably be changed to a TIME type instead.

Comment: pad out to 6 digits (`85323` -> `085323`), split on every 2nd char: `[08,53,23]`, recombine with `:` -> `08:53:23`

Comment: You should really be storing times in your database as the appropriate [temporal type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) instead of VARCHAR. That will allow you to do validation (e.g. reject values like `00:00:60`) and date/time math (e.g. 12:00:00 - 11:59:59 = 00:00:01 instead of 4041), among other things.

Comment: I think it should be changed to a TIME type myself, but TPTB are saying to stick with VARCHAR since several other various programs (which I have nothing to do with) are going to be using this data.  So I may not even need to change it to the proper TIME format after all.  Am awaiting confirmation on this

Comment: @BigRedEO: How would midnight be represented?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
s/(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1:$2:$3/;
```

No need to use a module :)

Comment: Added this to my script in my WHILE statement as

`$_ = s/(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1:$2:$3/ for $fields[15,26];` and although it didn't throw an error, it also did not format.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: The more source you show in the original question, the better answers you'll get. Try: `$fields[15] =~ s/...; $fields[26] =~ s/...;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -wle 'print join(":", unpack("(A2)*", sprintf("%06d", $ARGV[0])))' 85323
08:53:23

$ perl -wle 'print join(":", unpack("(A2)*", sprintf("%06d", $ARGV[0])))' 163211
16:32:11
```

Answer (score 0):

The other Regex solution provided does not account for adding the leading zero.

This will work fine if you have a newer perl that supports the `/r` return option on `s///` substitutions

```
$_ = sprintf('%06s', $_) =~ s/(..)(..)$/:$1:$2/r;
```

Replace `$_` with your variable name.

Alternatively, if your perl does not have the `/r` option, this will do the same thing...

```
( $t = sprintf('%06s', $t) ) =~ s/(..)(..)$/:$1:$2/;
```

Of course you could achieve the same thing with `Time::Piece` but for this particular task I assure you it's slower ( and more verbose )

```
$_ = Time::Piece->strptime(sprintf('%06s', $_), '%H%M%S')->hms;
```